# Javascript: besides "use strict", which other "use" directives are there?

Tags: javascript, strict, using-directives, use-strict

Besides `use strict`, which other `use` directives are there?

Comment: lol @ marc b. thanks for the link.  

I hope "RTFM" isn't your way of saying "I don't know".  I will read the manual, but look forward to getting a 1 paragraph answer from someone who knows, instead of having to wade through 255 of tech spec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some more examples that can be in the “directive prologue” (a section potentially usable by JavaScript engines):

- `'use strict';`
- `'use asm';`
  Mozilla's [asm.js](http://asmjs.org/) is a subset of the language, geared towards crunching numbers.
- `'use stricter';`
  Google's SoundScript. For fast OOP
  Has also some modes like:

  - `'use stricter+types';`
  - http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/soundscript.html
- `'use babel';`
  Used in [Atom.io](http://blog.atom.io/2015/02/04/built-in-6to5.html). (Was previously: `'use 6to5';`)

A tweet by [Jeremy Ashkenas](https://twitter.com/jashkenas/status/562996829777059840) suggests some further use of `+` and `-` prefixes in the same `'use ...';` string (`'use stricter +types -tco +jsx +asm +es2019-pre';`), but that seems to contradict the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-14.1) (further clarified in [kangax's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28890155/588079) and [Bergi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14969693/588079)).

Answer (score 4):

In case it's still of interest to anyone, I just ran across a "use asm" directive, for use with [asm.js](http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/).

So it seems like there may be additional "use" options added over time.

Answer (score 2):

Although it isn't a declarative like `"use strict";`, the next version of ECMAScript [(codenamed Harmony)](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aharmony) will apparently have an opt-in capability you can use in the `<script>` tag.

[From this article](http://www.2ality.com/2011/02/david-herman-on-ecmascriptnext.html):

> - opt-in via MIME type in script tag: `<script type="application/javascript;version=next">` (where “next” is a placeholder for something that has still to be determined)

The article is an overview of [this presentation by David Herman](http://blog.mozilla.com/dherman/2011/02/23/my-js-meetup-talk/), which is very much worth watching.

Comment: Just a note from the future, this never happened after all.