# ECMAScript multiple Prologue Directives

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Certain ECMAScript environments permit switiching into a special mode by means of a Directive Prologue. ECMAScript 5 has "use strict" and others such as [asm](http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/) have their own like "use asm".

The docs on [Directive Prologues](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-14.1) are written in a language that's a little to obtuse for my comprehension level. What is the correct way to construct a Directive Prologue with multiple Directives? My hunch is its:

```
function(){
  "use foo";
  "use bar";
}
```

But I'm not sure.

Comment: Your hunch is correct. My hunch is that no other directives than `"use strict"` are actually recognised by anyone, at least not in the browser environment.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. String literal followed by a semicolon (semicolon could be inserted automatically).

Comment: Firefox 22 should recognize `"use asm";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the correct way to construct a Directive Prologue with multiple Directives?

As the [spec you linked](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-14.1) says,

> a `Directive Prologue` is the *longest sequence* of [`ExpressionStatement` productions](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.4) occurring [at the begin of a script or function] and where each [of them] consists entirely of a [`StringLiteral`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.4).

So you can just string them together, every of these string-literal-statements is a Directive; and can have an implementation-specific meaning (only the Use-Strict-Directive is specified). Your hunch is correct, this should work:

```
"use bar"
"use strict"; 'use x';
'use foo';
```

Answer (score 1):

Since no one answered it, but I found the answer and it was confirmed in a comment I'm answering my own to close it.

Yes, to use multiple directives in a prologue list them one after the other like so:

```
function(){
  "use foo";
  "use bar";
}
```

or

```
function(){
  "use foo"; "use bar";
}
```