# Use strict is not working when I call my hoisted function

Tags: javascript, use-strict

I have the following code

```
"use strict";
x = 12;
function myFunction() {

}
myFunction();
```

so i am using `use strict` at the top of my script and now I am in strict mode - so I can't have undeclared variable like `x`

That gives me the following error in my console

`Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined`.

But when I execute this code

```
myFunction();
"use strict";
x = 12;
function myFunction() {

}

console.log('the script continues...')
```

I don't get the same error for my undeclared variable `x`. As you can see the script continues to execute.

Why is that ?
Why I don't get the same error when I try to call my hoisted function - so call the function before it is declared ?
Why it affects the global scope ?

Comment: Please always check the docs first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#strict_mode_for_scripts

Comment: I'm surprised I can't find a clean dupetarget for this. There are several questions about strict mode, but I don't see any on this aspect.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder FWIW, I'm also not aware of a specific duplicate. It might be mentioned in passing somewhere on SO but I think it's better to have an explicit Q&A pair explaining the behaviour.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28802885/1048572) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14902465/1048572)?

Comment: @Bergi - Seems a stretch to me though they're obviously closely related, but others may have a different view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it says in [MDN's documentation for strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#strict_mode_for_scripts), the `"use strict";` sequence is **only** a [strict mode directive](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-directive-prologues-and-the-use-strict-directive) if it's the first thing in the file other than a comment. With your function call above it, it's no longer the first thing in the file and so it isn't a strict mode directive; instead, it's just a freestanding string literal that nothing uses.

Since your code isn't in strict mode, `x = 12;` is assigning a value to an undeclared identifier, which (in loose mode) creates an *implicit global*. (More in my ancient post on my anemic old blog: [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).) This is one of the many reasons using strict mode is a Good Thing™, because with it assigning to an undeclared identifier is the error it always should have been.

---

Side note: Another way to use strict mode is to use native modules rather than the `"use strict";`. Modules, like nearly all new scopes in JavaScript since ES2015, are strict by default (and have other benefits, like their own scope and the ability to declare dependencies between them).

Comment: Which is of course mentioned right at the beginning of the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#strict_mode_for_scripts

Comment: @ChrisG - Yeah.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thanks for your comment. But my variable `x` is in global scope ? Why the function call affects the global scope for the strict mode ? Can you please explain

Comment: @someusername12 - I've added to the answer to address that comment.