# What is Prologue Directives?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I stumbled upon something people choose to call Prologue Directives. More commonly known with the *"use strict";* string literal in JavaScript. Which i already know all about. But the common denominator Prologue Directive. What it is? There's very little documentation available on this subject. Best one is the question i linked.

[ECMAScript multiple Prologue Directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902465/ecmascript-multiple-prologue-directives)

My questions are generic:

What are they?

What can they be used for?

Who uses them and why?

Can i make them?

Should i?

Comment: I don't really know enough about prologue directives in general to answer, but here's some more info on [Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) and [why you should use it](http://cjihrig.com/blog/javascripts-strict-mode-and-why-you-should-use-it/) if you can. Strict mode is the only one that I know of that is widely supported. As the question you linked states, [ASM.js](http://ejohn.org/blog/asmjs-javascript-compile-target/) is [supported/getting support](http://www.2ality.com/2013/02/asm-js.html#support) in a few browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for documentation. Just look in [the source](https://es5.github.io/#x14.1).

> A Directive Prologue is the longest sequence of ExpressionStatement
>   productions occurring as the initial SourceElement productions of a
>   Program or FunctionBody and where each ExpressionStatement in the
>   sequence consists entirely of a StringLiteral token followed a
>   semicolon. The semicolon may appear explicitly or may be inserted by
>   automatic semicolon insertion. A Directive Prologue may be an empty
>   sequence.
>
> A Use Strict Directive is an ExpressionStatement in a Directive
>   Prologue whose StringLiteral is either the exact character sequences
>   "use strict" or 'use strict'. A Use Strict Directive may not contain
>   an EscapeSequence or LineContinuation.
>
> A Directive Prologue may contain more than one Use Strict Directive.
>   However, an implementation may issue a warning if this occurs.

In other words, Directive Prologue is the longest sequence of string literal + semicolon at the exact start of function or program (top-level code):

```
(function(){
  "use strict"; // <-- Directive Prologue
})()
```

or:

```
(function() {
  // Directive Prologue start
  "foo bar"
  "baz";
  '123';
  '';
  // Directive Prologue end
})();
```

or:

```
'blah'; // <-- Directive Prologue (top-level code)
/* rest of the code here */
```

Notice that as soon as the string literal is not the first statement, it's no longer a Directive Prologue:

```
var x;
"use strict"; // <-- NOT a Directive Prologue
```

or:

```
(function() {
  1 + "use magic"; // <-- NOT a Directive Prologue
})();
```

Comment: What are they used for aside from "use strict"; ?

Comment: For other "non-standard" directives like "use asm", "use 6to5", etc. https://twitter.com/jashkenas/status/562996829777059840