# Known JavaScript Directives

Tags: javascript, directive, strict

The ECMAScript specification defines the Use Strict Directive, but permits implementations to define their own directives. From [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-directive-prologues-and-the-use-strict-directive):

> Implementations may define implementation specific meanings for
>   *ExpressionStatement* productions which are not a Use Strict Directive and which occur in a Directive Prologue.

What are the known implementation-specific directives? A quick Google search yields nothing other than `use strict`.

I can think of [`use asm`](http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/#validation) and [`use strong`](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Qk0qC4s_XNCLemj42FqfsRLp49nDQMZ1y7fwf5YjaI4/view#h.h2yh1tfb2qjk). Are there any others in use?

Comment: Related: [Javascript: besides “use strict”, which other “use” directives are there?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6999768/1529630)

Comment: I think I saw a library or framework which used its own directive, but I can't remember now.

Comment: I have seen "use babel"

Answer (score 0):

For Spidermonkey I found only [source](https://github.com/ricardoquesada/Spidermonkey/blob/4a75ea2543408bd1b2c515aa95901523eeef7858/js/src/vm/CommonPropertyNames.h#L197):

```
macro(useAsm, useAsm, "use asm")
macro(useStrict, useStrict, "use strict")
```

V8 same [source](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/47cce544a31ed5577ffe2963f67acb4144ee0232/src/ast/ast-value-factory.h#L273):

```
F(use_asm, "use asm")                            
F(use_strict, "use strict")
```