# Usage of the Term 'directive' for Control Flow Statements

Tags: javascript, terminology, directive

One [article](https://javascript.info/while-for) of a helpful JavaScript guide repeatedly refers to `break` and `continue` as 'directives', but I have only seen them referred to as 'control flow statements' before. What is the motivation for this terminology (particularly in JavaScript)?

My guess would be that it simply indicates that if we were to interpret the code into assembly, it would appear as a directive; I am wondering if there is any more meaning behind its usage, or if my guess is totally off base.

Comment: I guess if you aren't looking for official terminology, you can call any statement that is *directing* control flow a *directive*? Never seen this though. They're more commonly named "jump statements" or "control flow statements".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article is wrong, in JavaScript the term "directive" refers to a string value in a [directive prologue](https://262.ecma-international.org/14.0/#directive-prologue), like `"use strict";` and [others](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6999768/1048572).

As you say, `break;` and `continue;` are *statements*.